# How to save a google map direction into a postgresql/postgis database?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, google-maps

I have taken a direction(route) from google map.
[image]
Can I save this resultant direction/path/route to my postgresql/postgis database? How?

Comment: Whether possible or not, it will most certainly violate googles terms of service. See https://www.google.com/intl/en_en/help/terms_maps.html , number 2.

Comment: Then Can buffer that route and save the buffer in pgsql/postgis db?

Comment: That would still be a derivative work. Please read the limitations in Section 2 of the terms that til_b linked to. Perhaps you'd like to consider OpenStreetMap instead.

Comment: For OpenStreetMap routing please see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: But, OSM don't have data in the project area.

Comment: If you have a defined project area and are dependent on address data, maybe you could try to add the address data yourself? The street data is all there, see http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=15/-33.7550/150.9809 . But beware that you *may not* copy the address data from google maps. You'll have to get it on the ground, by looking at house number signs.

Comment: The image is not from the actual area. The actual area does not have enough street data for routing.

Comment: Does it have Bing image coverage? Bing images are a legal source for OSM tracing from imagery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't consider the legal aspect of this here is the solution for your need:

Use the Google Directions API to get the route between your locations.
A sample answer for such a directions api request can be seen here:

[Google Directions API sample response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#JSON)

The interesting part for you here is the 'overview_polyline' object and its attribute called 'points'.
This attribute contains the polyline itself as an encoded string, that you have to decode first in order to proceed. (there are tools and code freely available on the web for doing this)
Once you have your polyline decoded, you will probably have an array of coordinate pairs that make up the polyline itself.
What you have to do here, is to iterate through this array and form a WKT string from these coordinates. 
An example for such a string is:

> LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 2 1, 2 2)

Where the first member of a pair is the longitude and the second is the latitude value fetched from each point of the polyline.
Provided you are done with generating your WKT string, you can use ST_GeomFromText somehow like the below:

> ST_GeomFromText('your-wkt-here', 4326);

Where 4326 is your EPSG number.

And there you go. If you did everything correctly you finally have the polyline in your database.

Comment: is it legally forbidden to store routes from google directions API?

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for information about it and I found this, I think you can save the polyline like string and convert it in pairs of numbers (coordinates) or convert it and then store the coordinates(point fields)

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_LineFromEncodedPolyline.html

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm